# why am i getting error in JMeter Script Recording

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

why am I getting this error while recording a test script in Jmeter ??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because JMeter cannot create file `proxyserver.jks` in its working folder.

Most probably the user doesn't have [permissions](https://www.uwec.edu/kb/article/drives-establishing-windows-file-and-folder-level-permissions/) to write anything to the folder where you're launching JMeter from. Just grant the user rights for writing into that folder and the error will go away. If you don't have enough rights for that - copy JMeter to the folder where you have write access to (normally it's your [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory))

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates. If you don't want or cannot use the Chrome extension due to organization restrictions at least consider using [Recording Template](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building) as it creates a well-configured recording test plan in one click.